# Please i need some help php SELECT FROM WHERE

Tags: php

My problem is when i want to display someone's information from database using his **Username**:

i get this error  *this is Notice: Undefined variable: fname in /opt/lampp/htdocs/aa/hhh.php on line 27*  . .

```
<?php

include 'con_to_db.php';

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE Username='youba'" );

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

$fname = $row['Username'];
$age = $row['Age'];
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<h1> this is <?php echo $fname?> </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i use the **id** i get the information from database without any problems:

```
<?php

    include 'con_to_db.php';

    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE id='70'" );

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {

    $fname = $row['Username'];
    $age = $row['Age'];
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1> this is <?php echo $fname?> </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are u sure you have an user with username youba and also try using mysqli errors to see if there is obvious !!

Comment: My guess: the first query didn't execute, `while` loop didn't run, and the value of `$fname` wasn't set, so PHP threw an error. Print the raw query and execute it manually using phpMyAdmin or your MySQL command prompt. If it doesn't work, make sure there are records that match the given criteria.

Comment: @DarrenDavies: There's no scope issues here. `$fname` is inside `<?php` `?>` tags, so it should be fine (from what I can see).

Comment: as @AbhikChakraborty said, your issue is that there is no username youba in the table, so the code isn't entering in the while loop, so $fname isn't being set. To fix the issue before the while loop set $fname=''; $age=0; this way the warning will leave but fname will stay empty with this query

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not an error but a notice. However, this particular notice does hint at an error in the code, though not a syntax error, but a logical one: the body of your while loop does not get executed - i.e. you forgot to check if you get any result in the first place. (Also, if you would get *more* than one result, only the last one would be displayed).

Please check your database to see why the username is not there, though you obviously expect it to be.

Also, I assume (hope!) that your id field is numeric in the database, in which case you should not write quotes:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE id=70" );
```

Comment: the problem is when i use WHERE * = "text" . the error displayed . but if i use WHERE * = number . i have the result.

Comment: Yes, I (and everyone who commented above) got that. You are running two different queries, one of which gives a result and the other one doesn't. If you want to know why, run it manually (in PhpMyAdmin, for example), or inspect your table. Although my guess would be that there is no user by that username, there are also other possible causes. I can't look inside your database so you need to check that yourself.

Comment: i didn't run two queries . i run the first querier using " WHERE id =70 "  as a result youba is displayed . but when i try to " WHERE Username = 'youba' " i got the error . i mean i try with a deferent information like Gender , country , username the same error but when i use nembers like age , id with  WHERE i got no error , i hop you understand my problem , the prblem is WHERE *= number----> no error   WHERE * = " text "-------> error